# Conda: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2580' in position 644: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, conda

**Problem:**
When I try to switch the environment in conda I get an error and I can't activate the environment.
Strangely in the anaconda navigator, I can activate another environment.
I would rather not install conda new if possible.

**I tried:**
conda update conda
conda anaconda-navigator --reset

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "D:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 1093, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "D:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2580' in position 644: character maps to <undefined>
```

**My System/Enviromental variables from conda:**

```
CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
             CONDA_PREFIX=D:\Programme\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=D:\Programme\Anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=D:\Programme\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2
             GIT_LFS_PATH=D:\Programme\Git LFS
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\schup
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=D:\Programme\Anaconda3;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:
                          \Programme\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Library\bi
                          n;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Scripts;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\bin;D:\Program
                          me\Anaconda3;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\Programme
                          \Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\Library\bin;D:\Progr
                          amme\Anaconda3\Scripts;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\bin;D:\Programme\Anacond
                          a3\condabin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp;.;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-
                          bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\programdata\oracle\java\jav
                          apath;c:\programme  ▀jet java compiler\bin;c:\programme\notepad++\plug
                          ins\database;c:\programme\notepad++\plugins\php\ext;c:\programme\notep
                          ad++\plugins\php;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wb
                          em;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0;c:\program
                          files\dotnet;c:\programme\nodejs;c:\programme\git\cmd;c:\programme\ssh
                          programm;c:\programme\python 3.6;c:\programme\python 3.4.1;c:\programm
                          e\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin;d:\programme\java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;c:\program
                          files\git\cmd;d:\programme\mingw\bin;c:\users\schup\.dnx\bin;c:\progra
                          m files\microsoft dnx\dnvm;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\P
                          hysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:
                          \WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C
                          :\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;D:\Programme\Git LFS;C:\Program Files\Git\c
                          md;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\
                          System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;D:\Programme\MikeTex\miktex\bin\x64;C:\
                          Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.5.0;C:\Users\schu
                          p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Users\schup\App
                          Data\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\schup\AppData\Local\Mi
                          crosoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\schup\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\sch
                          up\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Programme\python\Scripts;D:\Programme\java\j
                          dk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Users\schup\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Prog
                          ram Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
                          2019.2.2\bin;.;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.
                          0\bin;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\envs\coursera;D:\Programme\Anaconda3\envs
                          \coursera\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib;C:\User
                          s\schup\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\schup\PycharmProj
                          ects\Workspace;C:\Users\schup\PycharmProjects\Workspace\pygame;C:\User
                          s\schup\PycharmProjects\Workspace\pygame snake;C:\Program
                          Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.2\bin;.;C:\Users\schup\AppData\Roaming\
                          Python\Python37\Scripts;G:\programs\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\x64
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Users\schup\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Mod
                          ules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;D:\Programme\A
                          utoIt3\AutoItX
               PYTHONPATH=D:\Programme\Python 3.6\Lib;D:\Programme\Python
                          3.6\DLLs;D:\Programme\Python 3.6\Lib\tkinter
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=D:\Programme\VirtualBox\

     active environment : base
    active env location : D:\Programme\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\schup\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\schup\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.1
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : D:\Programme\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\Programme\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\schup\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\schup\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Programme\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\schup\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\schup\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.1 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: I don't see a LANG or LC_ALL in there

Comment: what is that? What do you mean?

Comment: i had a similar error with the lambda character ('\u03bb'). cmder tried to print it and 
 the conda activator can't decode it. i simply deleted the lambda charater from cmder as described here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7445#issuecomment-406949659

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixing process:**
 1. open file `D:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py`
 2. Find the `decoding_table`
 3. add `'\u2580'`

I don't know what happened nor how and why it happened. So if someone knows I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`. No need to manually touch a decoding table for me.

Example:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 conda activate myenv
```

Answer taken from [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7445#issuecomment-774579800).

Answer (score 1):

This problem:

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2580' in position 644: character maps to*

could also be connected with encodings used in system generally. (Problem found mainly in Windows)

Solution is adding PYTHONUTF8=1 to the default environment variables:

set PYTHONUTF8=1

It will affect all Python 3.7+ applications on your system. If you have any Python 3.7+ applications which rely on the legacy system encoding, it is recommended to set the environment variable temporarily or use the -X utf8 command line option.

Here's [a link](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-597-enable-utf-8-mode-by-default-on-windows/3122) to full article.